# ATG 9.1 to ATG10.0 migration CRS errors

Tags: atg

I have done the migration from ATG9.1 to ATG 10.0. But, In ATG10.0 they have removed some of the classes. I'm getting an error in  **atg.projects.store.storeconfig.InternationalizationStoreConfigurationContainer**.

They have removed this class.I'm new to ATG. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

CRS is a demo application.  It is not backward compatible across releases.  You should install the version of CRS that is intended for your migration target version.